# How can stockbrokers be so cheap in the U.S.?

Tags: investing, broker, dividend-reinvestment

How do stockbrokers in the U.S. manage to be so cheap?
In Germany, I know a few brokers but at most of them, the cost of an order is over 5€ (approx. 6$) every time. In the states, you have brokers like M1 Finance where they invest your money from dividends automatically and with zero commission.
As they need to pay the stock exchanges too, how does this work? How do they afford this?

Comment: FYI 2 years ago around $6/trade was quite standard in the USA also, with only novelty brokerages like Robinhood and M1 offering free trades.  Then Vanguard removed the commission for ETF trades (while keeping it on ordinary stock) and that started a domino effect -- within about 6 months all the online trading platforms that had sufficient levels of automation announced free trades on stocks and ETFs.

Comment: A good answer should call out the economics both for individual stocks (things like order flow and borrowing stocks for shorting purposes) and for funds (where the management is paid a percentage of AUM and is thus is incentivised to pay for availability on various trading platforms, which amounts to a kickback paid out of the management fee).

Comment: I don't know that there's a definitive answer. There's no way to know the wholesale costs for all brokers, and many may use it as a loss leader, making up for it on high-touch brokerage fees and other fees. I think there's agreement on how we got here (competitive pricing) but how brokers make up for that lost revenue could vary.

Comment: Interactive Brokers was the first to offer across the board zero commission trading when it offered Interactive Brokers Lite service.  Schwab then following and it then cascaded as Ally, Fidelity, E-Trade and TD Ameritrade, E-Trade, Ally Invest and Fidelity followed.  Vanguard was very late to the game, several months later.

Comment: There are some rough breakdowns of brokerage revenue prior to commission elimination. I'll see it I can track it down.  For example, circa 3 years ago Schwab earned about 6% from commissions whereas TD Ameritrade earned around 30%.  When commissions were eliminated by the major discount brokers, that was the death knell for Ameritrade and we know how that ended up (bought by Schwab).  E*Trade wasn't as bad as Ameritrade (15-20% ?) but Morgan Stanley gobbled them up.

Comment: Please note that in Germany there are brokers with very low order fees or even no fees. Germans are mostly very, very conservative about money, therefore they stay with their local bank although they don't get any benefit from it. Thus, local banks won't change their order fees, because people just don't care, and accordingly there is no market pressure to reduce the fees. I have seen banks with minimum fee of 10€ per order and people with 5-digit depots paying those fees.

Comment: I think robinhood also brought about change in the sector with its 0 commissions. This prompted more brokerage companies to move to no commissions as well.

Comment: Zecco (since bought by Trade King, since bought by Ally) offered free trading before Robinhood existed. The very diversified brokers simply noticed commissions weren't a significant portion of revenue and all participated in a race to the bottom. Maybe Robinhood's popularity had something to do with it, but now that you can use a broker like Schwab or Fidelity for the same price as Robinhood and get access to all the ancillary services and support of Schwab or Fidelity or Ally I have absolutely no idea why anyone uses Robinhood.

Comment: I agree. Given that  major discount brokers offer far more and far better services than Robinhood and these major discount brokers are now commission free, it makes no sense to trade at Robinhood.  If you're a serious investor who needs better services and more than a stripped down platform, you should be trading elsewhere.

Comment: I'm too lazy to actually write an answer as there is already an accepted one, but the premise of this question seems indeed to be seriously flawed, as there actually are quite a few free brokers in Germany and the limitations & how they make money with a zero comission model is well known: [https://www.justetf.com/de/news/etf/kostenlose-online-broker-auf-dem-pruefstand.html](https://www.justetf.com/de/news/etf/kostenlose-online-broker-auf-dem-pruefstand.html)

Comment: @s1lv3r - If you have additional information that will help the OP understand the situation  then you should write an answer, even if another one has been accepted. He can change his mind about the accepted answer.

Comment: @BobBaerker: Vanguard may have been late to "across-the-board" zero commissions, but they had much earlier gone to $0 ETF trades which put the pressure on other brokerages (and eventually the dominoes fell full circle and forced Vanguard to adjust commissions on stock trades also).

Comment: @Ben Voigt - Vanguard's $0  ETF trades did not put significant pressure on other brokerage firms because Vanguard restricted frequent trading.  In addition, it's not a sophisticated platform for traders so that further limited the impact of no free ETF trades.  The free ETF trading was a loss leader. Vanguard is more of an asset manager with small  profits from trading and much larger revenues coming from “Sticky Money” (long term investors buying annuities, managed money, financial planning, trust services, etc.). The real pressure came from Robinhood's free trading and its rapid growth.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Traditionally, commissions were a large part of the annual revenues for brokerage firms.  As discount brokerage became more popular and as the industry evolved, brokers diversified into other areas.

In recent years before their elimination, commissions were a minor fraction of most brokerages’ revenues. Commissions made up 28% of revenue at TD Ameritrade, but just 17% at E*TRADE and 6% at Charles Schwab. Here's an article that [breaks down brokerage revenues](https://daytradereview.com/how-stock-brokers-make-money/#:%7E:text=%20Other%20Ways%20Brokers%20Make%20Money%20%201,clients%20will%20place%20losing%20trades%20and...%20More%20) before commissions were eliminated.

Other sources of revenue for brokers include:

- interest on cash balances
- margin lending
- borrow fees from shorters
- payment for order flow
- sale of annuities and insurance
- asset management fees
- mutual fund/ETF management fees
- financial planning fees
- market making

From the linked article, the lion's share of broker revenue comes from interest: 67% at E*Trade, 60% at Interactive Brokers, 57% at Schwab and 51% at TD Ameritrade.

Comment: Applying this to Germany, as asked, and other markets: as long as they all charge huge fees, they _can_ continue to do so. Once the first broker breaks ranks and offers ‘free trading‘, they‘ll be all under pressure to follow (or lose customers). Same process as in the US.

Comment: @Aganju: A cartel, then?

Comment: @Aganju: There are low fee brokers since several years, still local banks didn't reduce their fees. Stock trading is a niche, Germans rather put their money into a traditional pension plan.

Comment: @Chris which brokers are you refering to? i dont know any broker wich offers low fees for more than a year because of marketing.

Comment: @clomee: there are several ones targeting already experienced users, e.g. CapTrader and Lynx Broker with less than 0,15% per order, which are using the international Interactive Broker platform. At the moment "etoro" is also running a lot of marketing campaigns aimed at beginners with zero fees (I haven't digged deeper if there is any hidden disadvantage).

Comment: So you're essentially saying that they don't make money in the U.S because they have other income streams? Similar to other businesses that change a lot of money B2B but almost nothing B2C?

Comment: (1) I'm saying that brokerage firms make money despite charging no commissions.  For example, Schwab's net income for the quarter ending September 30, 2020 was $615 million. (2) I don't see the relevance of B2B and B2C to a no commission situation.