# Assuming I have an AI Algorithm. What license I need to deploy the algorithm?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis

i am working on general purpose AI, so I have a background in HMM's, RL. I am in the process of developing an app that uses online stream of data from multiple sources and produces a prediction (currently using past stream as present stream).

What licenses would l need to deploy my algorithm (similar to high frequency trading)?

Is it even possible without incorporating?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What does 'deploy' mean? Will you use it yourself, or are you asking about selling it / licensing its use?

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica by deploy I mean test it in real environment! Get online data and make bettings. Much like those binary trading apps

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about personal finance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm uses a computer programs to trade a strategy at high speed and volume based on the rule structure  that it contains. In order to trade with one, you need sufficient capital,  a trading platform, and fast internet connectivity.

In the US, SEC (and some state) regulations come into play if you raise money and trade for others.  A brokerage firm is subject to FINRA rules if involved algorithmic trading. There is no licensing requirement for an individual to use one.  If in another country, google for local laws.

Comment: when you say a trading platform, when do you exactly mean? Is it something like Forex Trading platform, the only problem with such options are the commission makes trading less viable. I am looking for bare-metal solutions where I can directly obtain the stream of data and make live betting (which I dont know if the brokerage firm will place my betting on my behalf)

Comment: "Trading platform" is a subjective description. Any online broker providing quotes could be construed as offering a trading platform. However, many of these are are not designed or useful for trading as they offer only basic order entry screens. AFAIC, a trading platform is one designed for sophisticated traders, allowing them to utilize in house algorithms or implement their own. If you use a broker to execute your trades, you pay their commission rate. Today, many charge no commissions at all. Live streaming data will cost you a bundle to obtain on your own.  Can't help you with Forex.

Comment: this makes so much sense. you mentioned that 'Today, many charge no commission at all' whats the catch here?

Comment: `Whats the catch here?` If you're alluding to how can brokers charge no commissions, read this: [How can stockbrokers be so cheap in the U.S.?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/135000/how-can-stockbrokers-be-so-cheap-in-the-u-s/135002#135002).